# Should AbstractListenerContainerFactory really close the consumer it uses to check topics

Tags: spring-kafka

In org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer, when starting the container, the checkTopics method checks if the subscribed topic exists on the broker using a Kafka consumer that is created in a try with resources block.

When the consumer is closed, the closure cascades down to many Closeable associated objects, notably the key and value deserializers (see org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer). In a Spring application, Deserializers are generally declared as beans so there is only one instance in the factory of each type, and while most deserializers implement close as a no-op, I have come across cases where closing a Deserializer renders it unusable from that point on.

It seems to me that while closing a consumer sounds reasonable, given that multiple instances are spun up by Spring and the one created here is just a throwaway, the cascade down to Deserializer beans is an undesirable consequence that maybe wasn't noticed when the AbstractMessageListenerContainer was written.

There is a workaround - when creating the KafkaListenerContainerFactory just call

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
```

but this removes the safety check for topic existence and seems like a bit of a hack. Is closing the consumer really the right thing to do in AbstractMessageListenerContainer?

Answer (score 0):

We can [and will](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1074) use an `AdminClient` instead of a `Consumer` to check that the topic(s) exist.

However, this is not a panacea since `stop()`ping a container also closes the `Consumer`(s) so the same problem would exist when the container(s) are restarted.

In cases like this, it's better to let Kafka manage the lifecycle of the deserializer instead of declaring it as a bean.

Comment: That makes sense - I must double check the source code - presumably if the deserializer is just specified in properties/yml then instances are created appropriately as required when new Kafka consumers are created - it's when there isn't a no-args constructor or some other bean dependent initialization is required that I have declared them as beans and set them on the container.

Comment: However, looking at DefaultConsumerFactory, this is designed explicitly with single instances of key and value deserializers that are shared between all the created consumer instances. Would it be better for this class to take in DeserializerFactories that provide new instances per consumer so that any lifecycle events such as closure are safe to be cascaded down?

Comment: Yes, we can do something like that; please open a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues); and [contributions are welcome!](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc).

Comment: Thanks - will do, and would love to contribute - having any of my code get into Spring source would make me very very happy :-)

Comment: Cool; I am thinking `SerdeFactory` interface with six methods - key/value serializer/deserializer and key/value SerDes for Kafka Streams (all methods having no-op defaults). With one implementation that gets (up to) 6 bean names and the `ApplicationContext` - uses `getBean()` each time so prototype-scoped beans will provide a new one for each producer/consumer/stream. We can discuss further when you open an issue.

Comment: Ha ha yes, I was thinking smaller scale - where DefaultConsumerFactory takes in just key/value deserializer instances (As it only relates to consumers) have a new variation that takes in suppliers of deserializers, and the DefaultConsumerFactory becomes a delegator where it uses a supplier function that always returns the instance it's been given. Hence backward compatible but avoiding any duplication of code, and allowing any function that provides a deserializer so up to client whether they spin up new ones or re-initialize existing ones. Will chat further on issue, I'll open it this weekend

Comment: Sounds good, the delegator approach sounds reasonable; thanks; but `Serializer`s have `close()` too so, theoretically, the same problem can apply there as well.

Comment: true - there's the DefaultKafkaProducerFactory I hadn't noticed. Probably makes sense then to have a more general factory with defaults for wider applicability